# Internet explorer showing html as text instead of rendering the html

Tags: windows, html, encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a basic html file that opens in IE](https://superuser.com/questions/22518/create-a-basic-html-file-that-opens-in-ie)

I am using a tool that has an embedded browser control that is failing to render HTML.

Is there some kind of file association or encoding default that could have been changed?

I am running Windows XP.

[image]

Comment: What is telling the program that it should be rendered as HTML?  Is there a file extension or setting somewhere?  Perhaps you should just uninstall and reinstall the software?

Comment: I tried doing a clean install of the software, same issue

Comment: What is the name of the program? This may be a problem with the program you are using.

Aditttionally, this question _may_ be better suited for Doctype.

Comment: XMetaL Author Enterprise it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create a basic html file that opens in IE](https://superuser.com/questions/22518/create-a-basic-html-file-that-opens-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this kind of thing when javascript is disabled.  Some sites that use AJAX require the javascript so it knows what to do with the text.  I am not sure if this is your problem however. I would need more info.

Comment: Javascript is not disabled in IE.  And infact I get javascript vague errors when trying to close XMetaL after this issue occurs.

Comment: Ok, if that is not the problem, it is possible this issue might require an update to your javascript installation.  Does the site require active-x to be enabled?  Did it ever work? Did this just start happening all of the sudden or has this always been the behavior you see?

Comment: It just started happening.  It was working before.  I think the file association for html might be messed up.  But don't know how to fix it.